# How to use multiple field separators in awk in CentOS minimal install

Tags: linux, awk, centos, field, separator

I have an input log file that looks like this:

```
Sep 24 22:44:57 192.168.1.9 cts4348 ADD ahay844,Akeem Haynes,Men,Athletics,AT,canada
Sep 24 22:46:26 192.168.1.9 cts4348 ADD afro438,Adam Froese,Men,Hockey,HO,canada
Sep 24 22:47:09 192.168.1.9 cts4348 ADD atra522,Allison Track,CT,canada
```

I would like to output just the column that has "ADD" and the two columns that follow which is the username and full name. After I pull that information I will be generating an account based on the username and a comment with the full name. I need to use the "space" and "," as a field separator.

The command I am currently using is:

```
cat cts4348 | awk -F' ' -v OFS=',' '{print $6 " " $7 $8}'
```

And here is a same of my output:

```
ADD ahay844,AkeemHaynes,Men,Athletics,AT,canada
ADD afro438,AdamFroese,Men,Hockey,HO,canada
ADD atra522,AllisonTrack,CT,canada
```

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: ( use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box on highlighted text to format as code/data/output. )  Good luck.

Comment: The last line in the sample input which ends `Allison Track,CT,canada` seems to be missing fields that are present in the first two lines.  Maybe `Allison Smith,Women,Track,CA,Canada`?

Comment: @John1024 yea I think someone helped me by editing it and the end was cut off?

Comment: @ChristopherJohnson : At the bottom of your Q you can see my "icon" (shellter), click on the link "edited (n) days ago". You'll see that my edit didn't create missing fields on the last line of sample data. In any case you can always put in the missing data. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using awk

This approach sets the field separator to be either `ADD` or `,`:

```
$ awk -F' ADD |,' '/ADD/{print "ADD", $2, $3}' File
ADD ahay844 Akeem Haynes
ADD afro438 Adam Froese
ADD atra522 Allison Track
```

Because space-separation is not used, this will work even if the person has a middle name.

*Limitation:*  If the other fields were to contain space-A-D-D-space, then the output might be wrong.

#### Using sed

```
$ sed -nE '/ ADD /{s/([^ ]* ){5}//; s/(,[^,]*),.*/\1/p}' File
ADD ahay844,Akeem Haynes
ADD afro438,Adam Froese
ADD atra522,Allison Track
```

On lines containing `ADD`, this uses two substitute commands:

1. `s/([^ ]* ){5}//` removes the first five space-separated fields.
2. `s/(,[^,]*),.*/\1/` removes all but the first comma-separated fields.

Again, because space-separation is not used, this will work even if the person has a middle name.

Comment: This is solution could work for me since I could still use $1 to pipe the information before the "ADD" to single out the date and time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'[ ,]' '{print $6,$7","$8,$9}' file

ADD ahay844,Akeem Haynes
ADD afro438,Adam Froese
ADD atra522,Allison Track
```

Answer (score 1):

with `grep`

```
$ cat ip.txt 
Sep 24 22:44:57 192.168.1.9 cts4348 ADD ahay844,Akeem Haynes,Men,Athletics,AT,canada
Sep 24 22:46:26 192.168.1.9 cts4348 ADD afro438,Adam Froese,Men,Hockey,HO,canada
Sep 24 22:47:09 192.168.1.9 cts4348 ADD atra522,Allison Track,CT,canada

$ grep -o 'ADD[^,]*,[^,]*' ip.txt 
ADD ahay844,Akeem Haynes
ADD afro438,Adam Froese
ADD atra522,Allison Track
```

- `ADD[^,]*` ADD followed by zero or more non-comma characters
- `,` comma
- `[^,]*` zero or more non-comma characters
- Since `*` is greedy, it will try to match as many characters as possible

Answer (score 1):

awk with split:

```
$ awk -F, '{ split($1, a, " "); print "ADD", a[length(a)] "," $2 }' file.txt

ADD ahay844,Akeem Haynes
ADD afro438,Adam Froese
ADD atra522,Allison Track
```